# Angular directive not appending data

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I try to append some content via directive but never appears in view. If I log the compiled scope I can see the Object.

```
angular.module('blancAppApp')
  .controller('SlugCtrl', function ($scope, WpApi, $compile, $filter, ngProgressLite) {

    // the Content to be rendered.
   $scope.maincontent = [];
   // load remote data from the server.
   function loadRemoteData() {
   // The WpApiService returns a promise.
        WpApi.getContents()
        .then(
            function( post ) {       
                applyRemoteData( post );       
            });    
    }

     // apply the remote data to the local scope.
    function applyRemoteData( newContents ) {    
        $scope.maincontent  = $compile( newContents[0].content )($scope);  
        console.log($scope.maincontent); // Object getting logged
    }     

}).directive('maincontent', function() {

    return {
            restrict: 'A',
                scope: {
                    maincontent: '=maincontent'
                },

                link: function (scope, element, attrs) {  

                       element.append( scope.maincontent  );
                    }
                };
});
```

**Markup**

```
<div id="main-content" data-maincontent="maincontent"></div>
```

Comment: I don't think scope.maincontent is passed by reference, but it makes a copy. And i guess at the point of it passing it to the directive it has not returned yet from the server. Try and console.log scope.maincontent in your directive link function and see if it is called before the log in the "applyRemoteData"-function

Comment: yes you are right `console.log(scope.maincontent)` in `link:function() {}` is getting called first and shows `[]` empty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register a watcher on the scope because the request is async:

```
var unregister = scope.$watch('maincontent', function(val) {
  if(!val) { return; }
  element.append( val  );
  unregister();
});
```

Comment: Do I place the watcher inside `link: function(){}` of my directive ? if so I get `Error: unregister is not a function`

Comment: what version of angular you use?

Comment: @fefe scope.$watch should return a function -> https://code.angularjs.org/1.2.25/docs/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$watch

Comment: thank you very much I still work on it to bring it up but(angular newbie) it seems this is what I need